# Как узнать установлена ли определенная программа на телефоне?

Tags: java, android

Мне в приложении нужно давать возможность пользователю отправлять сообщения через месседжеры, которые установлены у него на телефоне, как узнать установлен ли у пользователя Viber, WhatsApp и тому подобные программы?

Comment: Зачем? Правильным решением является отправить интент с ACTION_SEND и позволить пользователю выбрать приложение для отправки сообщения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

В `packagename` передавать имя пакета приложения. Например, у вайбера это `com.viber.voip`